# Why can't I use my extension method in a delegate in the Razor WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm using the MVC 3 introduced WebGrid, but can't can't apply my own extension methods when passing a delegate for the `format` param.

Using:

```
Grid.Column("MyProperty", "MyProperty", 
format: @<span class="something">@item.MyProperty.MyExtensionMethodForString()</span>)
```

I got

```
ERROR: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'MyExtensionMethodForString'
```

I've tried casting, not to avail

```
Grid.Column("MyProperty", "MyProperty", 
format: @<span class="something">@((string)(item.MyProperty).MyExtensionMethodForString())</span>)
```

If I use an standard method, it works:

```
Grid.Column("MyProperty", "MyProperty", 
format: @<span class="something">@(Utils.MyExtensionMethodForString(item.MyProperty))</span>)
```

I've also tried to put the extension in the same namespace, with no results.

**How can I use my beloved extensions?**

**Edit**: The namespace per se it's not the problem, the namespace where the extension is available for all the views and classes, and I can use it in the same view without problem. The problem is when using it in the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a limitation of the WebGrid or Razor. It's a limitation of the C# `dynamic` type. You cannot use extension methods on dynamic. The format helper takes a `Func<dynamic, object>` as an argument, so the `item` parameter is a dynamic type.

I [wrote about this exact issue](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/171/Why-You-Can%27t-Use-Extension-Methods-With-A-WebGrid) a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine for me.  Static class:

```
public static class TestExtensions
{
    public static string Foo(this HtmlHelper html, Func<object, HelperResult> func)
    {
        return func(null).ToHtmlString();
    }

    public static string MyStringExtension(this string s)
    {
        return s.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Controllers

@Html.Foo(@<text>@Html.Raw("Hello")</text>)
```

The page prints out:

> Hello

However, this version of the Index.cshtml:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Controllers

@Html.Foo(@<text>@("Hello".MyStringExtension())</text>)
```

Prints out your error message:

> CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'MyStringExtension' and no extension method 'MyStringExtension' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So I suspect Jon was correct and this is a limitation with Razor.  (why it works with HtmlHelper leaves me a bit mystified though)

Comment: Much simpler example. I guess I'll just live with the workaround :). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found this SO question by way of researching why the following line was throwing the same error:

```
@a.GetAttribute<ActionLabelAttribute>().ActionLabel
```

Turns out it could easily be corrected by enclosing this line in parenthesis, like so:

```
@(a.GetAttribute<ActionLabelAttribute>().ActionLabel)
```

Note: The `GetAttribute` extension method comes from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5354/73862).