# MVC WebGrid - How to call a method on WebGridRow item / model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

When using WebGrids, I find that I can access properties on the model bound to the WebGrid, but I can't access methods on the Model itself.

As an example, this works:

```
// Accessing a property of item works
reportGrid.Column("", header: "First Name", format: item => item.firstName )
```

But this does not work:
(I am showing a trivial example, but for my case I must call a method on the User object itself.)

```
// Accessing a method on item does not work 
reportGrid.Column("", header: "First Name Backwards", format: item => item.firstNameBackwards() )

=> error: 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'getFullName'
```

This seems related to the following:

[Why can't I use my extension method in a delegate in the Razor WebGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580257/why-cant-i-use-my-extension-method-in-a-delegate-in-the-razor-webgrid)
  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/171/Why-You-Can%27t-Use-Extension-Methods-With-A-WebGrid

I don't see a way to apply these solutions to my problem. As Mike Brind states:

> The argument that the WebGridColumn's Format parameter takes is a
>   delegate: Func. What this means is that you have to
>   pass in a dynamic type, and then something is done to it before it is
>   returned as an object.
>
> ...
>
> When you try to use an extension method, the Compiler will check the
>   type you are trying to use it on to see if such a method exists. If it
>   doesn't. it will check any base classes that the type derives from to
>   see if they contain a formal method with the right name.

It seems like my method should be found, but perhaps not because the model bound to the WebGrid is actually a paging model that contains `IList<T> LineItems` which hold my User references.

Is there any way to cast or get a reference to the User object itself so I can call methods defined on it in addition to accessing its properties?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around this problem, but I'm still hopeful there is a better way. I would appreciate any feedback on this or alternate solutions.

In exploring this issue and examining some of my other WebGrid code, I found that I am able to access 2nd order methods defined against objects that can be accessed through properties on the model object bound to the WebGrid.

Example (simplified):

```
reportGrid.Column("", header: "First Name Backwards", 
  format: item => item.BestFriend.firstNameBackwards() )
=> Works!
```

Taking this a step further, I traced the bi-directional relationship back to the original object so I could call its methods:

```
// Assume all best-friend relationships are reciprocal 
reportGrid.Column("", header: "First Name Backwards", 
  format: item => item.BestFriend.BestFriend.firstNameBackwards() )

=> Works!
```

With this in mind, I modified my User model to contain a reference to itself:

```
    public User() {
        this._self = this; // Initialize User object with a reference to itself
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public User _self { get; set; }
```

Solution - now I can call methods defined against the User model using the _self property.

```
reportGrid.Column("", header: "", 
  format: item => Helper.userTML(item._self.firstNameBackwards() ) )

=> Works!
```

Answer (score 0):

> In exploring this issue and examining some of my other WebGrid code, I found that I am able to access 2nd order methods defined against objects that can be accessed through properties on the model object bound to the WebGrid.

I had the same issue and per this comment, I had figured out it was because I didn't expose the data members of the model. Set your firstName definition to public and that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way that worked for me was using a getter in the model class.

In your model class (User?):

```
public string firstNameBackwards
{
    get 
    { 
        var firstNameBackwards = firstName;
        // Do something here
        return firstNameBackwards; 
    }
}
```

In your webgrid:

```
reportGrid.Column("", header: "First Name Backwards", format: item => item.firstNameBackwards )
```